# SET and SELECT query not executing when run in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code -:

```
$q = "SET @session = '1', @buddys = '12,7,10', @rejects = 'post_0'; SELECT f.* FROM feed as f"; $r = mysqli_num_rows($q);.
```

This results in this error -: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT f.* FROM feed as f' at line 3`.

But surprisingly, when the same mysql query is run in phpmyadmin it runs as needed.

Whats the matter? Thanks for help...

Comment: `*` is a reserver mysql symbol

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the semicolone `;` before select

try replace it by comma `,`

like that

```
 $q = "SET @session = '1', @buddys = '12,7,10', @rejects = 'post_0' , SELECT f.* FROM feed as f";
  $r = mysqli_num_rows($q);
```

or you ould also separate your query like that

```
   $q = "SET @session = '1', @buddys = '12,7,10', @rejects = 'post_0' ";
   $q .= "SELECT f.* FROM feed as f";
```